# vba "Application-defined or object-defined error" and "expression not defined in context" when watched

Tags: excel, vba

I have this `VBA` code that worked perfectly fine before yet suddenly not anymore. It returns

> application-defined or object defined error

now, when I watched the failed line, it says

> expression not defined in context

Basically, what this macro does is to let people choose pivot table filters by several times in a group, rather than one by one.  Below is the code, any help will be strongly appreciated.

```
Sub AdvancedFilter1()
    Dim ws
    Set ws = Workbooks("Bayer IB.xlsm").Worksheets("Pivots")
    ws.Activate
    Dim pv3
    Dim pv4
    Set pv3 = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Shipped Date FY")
    Set pv4 = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Shipped Date FY")
    Workbooks("Bayer IB.xlsm").Worksheets("Pivots").Activate
   If ws.Range("B1").Activate Then
        If ActiveCell.Value = "10" Then
        With pv3
        .PivotItems("2007").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2008").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2009").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2010").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2011").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2012").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2013").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2014").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2015").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2016").Visible = True
           End With

        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "2" Then
        With pv3
        .PivotItems("2007").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2008").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2009").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2010").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2011").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2012").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2013").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2014").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2015").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("2016").Visible = True
           End With


    End If
  End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$B$1"
        If Target = "10" Then
        Call AdvancedFilter1


        ElseIf Target = "2" Then
        Call AdvancedFilter1

        ElseIf Target = "3" Then
        Call AdvancedFilter1


        ElseIf Target = "5" Then
        Call AdvancedFilter1

         ElseIf Target = "7" Then
        Call AdvancedFilter1

        End If
        'TO PREVENT AUTOMATIC REDIRECT TO 'J3'
        Range("B1").Select


  End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("B1").Select` should that be outside the `case` or a `case else`? You don't need `Workbooks("Bayer IB.xlsm").Worksheets("Pivots").Activate`. It would help if you specify which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Range("B1").Select is outside of case else.  It's either one of the .PivotItems("2007").Visible = True that's throwing out the error, depending if I select "10" or "2" in the worksheet.

Comment: Does `PivotItems("2007")` exist? `Range("B1").Select` is inside the `case statement`.

Comment: Yes, every pivot item, including "2007", exists and contains data in the pivot table.  I also tried delete " .PivotItems("2007").Visible = False" since it throws error, but then the error goes down to  ".PivotItems("2008").Visible = False", if I delete that, it goes down to "2009" row and so on......

Comment: That means `Set pv3 = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Shipped Date FY")` is bad.

Comment: Changed it around and made sure all the object names are correct, still no...  below is how that line looks right now:ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivots").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Shipped Date FY")

Comment: You originally had `Workbooks("Bayer IB.xlsm")`, not `thisworkbook`. I don't use pivot tables so I don't know what else to tell you :/ Perhaps comment out the `Range("B1").Select`

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add an update to this question... I used the same code in another file, and it worked there. I still don't know why it won't work before, but this code is working out now, though in another workbook...

Thanks anyone who took time reading this and @findwindow's assistant.